# how to change color of button after clicking button in angular

Tags: html, angular, angular6

i need to change button color into red (primary color to red color) after clicking button, please help me how to change color after clicking button.

```html
 <td>
      <button mat-icon-button color="primary">
        <mat-icon>remove_circle</mat-icon>
      </button>
      </td>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implement this logic in your code.

```js
var isClicked = false;
```

```css
.myClass{
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<td>
      <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="isClicked = !isClicked" [class.myClass]="isClicked">
        <mat-icon>remove_circle</mat-icon>
      </button>
      </td>
```

Comment: @Richards, please let me know if it works for you or need further assistance :)

Comment: thank u @Harunur i am trying. .myClass{
  color : red;
} can i use these in component file.

Comment: Put this class in your component.css file or whichever style file you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
// .ts file  
flag : any = false;

btnClick(){
    this.flag = true;
}
```

Set css for color

```
::ng-deep .colorRed{
    color:red
}
```

In your `HTML` file

```
  // To apply color on row just put ngClass on tr  
  <tr [ngClass]="{ 'colorRed' :flag }">
    <td>
      <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="btnClick()">
          <mat-icon>remove_circle</mat-icon>
       </button>
     </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: thank you @sachin but whats happening means it should only change particular selected color but it is changing completed rows color. will you help me in these.

Comment: @Richards I have update my answer. Please look in to that. You just have to apply class on tr where you want to set as you can see in my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using @angular/material, you should bind to the color @Input of their component rather than just adding a css-class of your own.

That way you do not have to worry about css-priority and your code will not be fragile to changes in the @angular/material implementation of component color.

```
  <button mat-icon-button 
          [color]="buttonColor"
          (click)="buttonColor = 'warn'">
    <mat-icon>remove_circle</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

and in your component

```
   buttonColor: ThemePalette = 'primary';
```

If your warn-color is not red, then consider changing your theme or [making a new theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).