# How to change the background colour when the mat-button is clicked - Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

For example: https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview
when I click on any of these buttons, there is a grey background effect added onto the button.

I have tried ngdeep and targetting the mat button's status such as focus and active. But, even with a background colour such as red, I can still see the grey and with background as white it is apparent the grey is still there.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of the button's behaviour  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52962829/how-to-change-color-of-button-after-clicking-button-in-angular

Comment: @SarahCox thanks for the link, but I tried those options and it did not work

Comment: @Gintoki Sorry that didn't work for you. I'm glad Nirmalya Roy could offer a good solution for you though!

Answer (score 1):

You can off the ripple effect of the material button using disableRipple as true. So that grey background effect won't come on click of button.

```
<button mat-raised-button [disableRipple]="true">Basic</button>
```

You need to add the below configuration in root module.ts file

```
const globalRippleConfig: RippleGlobalOptions = {
  disabled: true,
  animation: {
    enterDuration: 300,
    exitDuration: 0
  }
};

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: globalRippleConfig}
  ]
})
```

Check the detailed link here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvbzzq-yhgy5c?file=src/app/material-module.ts

Comment: That works! Thank you! Do you know if it is possible to change it in css? I have a lot of mat buttons in my project already.

Comment: Based on the material angular documentation this is the only way. If this answer is correct please make this answer correct.

Comment: Please check my modified answer. In this way, you can actually off ripple from whole project.